# Yii2:how to check multiple checkbox

Tags: yii2

I have grid. Here I have display all the records. I have header check box, and row check box.
If i click header check box the all the row check box will check and if i check all the row check box then header check box will select. Hoe to do this in yii2.

Answer (score 0):

The basic component gridview provided by Yii2 not have this feature. then you should write all that is necessary to integrate this functionality. The easiest way is to use the extension or component ready. for example for this kind of functionality I found very useful component [kartik builder tabular form](http://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form)

This extension provides many additional funzinalità including management of columns check box is supported with specific extensions type of column

In particular this extension provide a specific `check box component' for yuor propose.

```
[
    'class' = '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-row-select'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-all-select'],
]
```

But attention is not an easy  component   to use. require a good familiarity  whit  Yii2

Comment: This is only a part of the code. You need install  the extension, configure correctly your gridview with (also) this part of code. I  think you should first  read deeply the link provided and after evalute what you want to do . the code is not a plug and play code....